# Refreshing DOM with new data ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, dom, render

Everything works with my code as far as the API call and answer. My problem lies with displaying the data. Everything looks great on the DOM on the first render, but any search after the first one everything stacks on top of each other as opposed to refreshing.. I was wondering how I could erase the data from the first render and refill the Movie component with the new data. All help is super appreciated!I figure it's a small problem, probably with hooks, but I've been scratching my head for too long.

this block is API call

```
const [movies, setMovie] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const handleInput = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoaded(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) {
      getMovies(search);
      setIsLoaded(false);
    } // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [isLoaded]);

Axios.get(
      `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${search}&plot=full&apikey=183ac7ca`
    ).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      let movieObject = {
        title: res.data.Title,
        poster: res.data.Poster,
        rated: res.data.Rated,
        released: res.data.Released,
        runtime: res.data.Runtime,
        genre: res.data.Genre,
        director: res.data.Director,
        writer: res.data.Writer,
        actors: res.data.Actors,
        plot: res.data.Plot,
        awards: res.data.Awards,
        id: res.data.imdbID
      };

      setMovie([...movies, movieObject]);
    });
```

This block is my movie component where I map the data to JSX

```
  return movies.map(movie => (
    <div key={movie.id}>
      <div className="poster-title">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img
              height="450"
              width="350"
              className="poster"
              alt=""
              src={movie.poster}
            ></img>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h1 className="title" key={movie.title}>
              {movie.title}
            </h1>
            <small>{movie.runtime}</small>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="rating-genre">
        <h1 className="rating" key={movie.id}>
          {movie.rated}
        </h1>
        <h1>{movie.genre}</h1>
      </div>
      <h3 className="plot">{movie.plot}</h3>
      <div className="movie-info">
        <p>Director: {movie.director}</p>
        <p>Writer(s): {movie.writer}</p>
        <p>Leading Actors: {movie.actors}</p>
        <p>{movie.awards}</p>
        <small className="released">Released: {movie.released}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
setMovie([...movies, movieObject]);
```

You are using a spread operator to copy the existing movies and append the new movies.

Just remove the spread

```
setMovie([movieObject]);
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something small like that. Thank you so much! still getting familiar with the spread operator..